# Plotly domain variable explained (Multiple graphs)

Tags: python, plotly

I am looking at the 'Pie Chart Subplots' section (last one on page) of the following tutorial https://plot.ly/python/pie-charts/.

I cant figure out how to understand the domain variable when it comes to plotting multiple graphs at once. For instance:

```
        {
        'labels': ['1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th', '5th'],
        'values': [38, 27, 18, 10, 7],
        'type': 'pie',
        'name': 'Starry Night',
        'marker': {'colors': ['rgb(56, 75, 126)',
                              'rgb(18, 36, 37)',
                              'rgb(34, 53, 101)',
                              'rgb(36, 55, 57)',
                              'rgb(6, 4, 4)']},
        'domain': {'x': [0, .48],
                   'y': [0, .49]},
        'hoverinfo':'label+percent+name',
        'textinfo':'none'
    },
```

will plot a pie chart in the bottom left coordinates.

Can someone explain how the domain variable (and its x and y components) works in practice in plotly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's just use Javascript because it can be executed here. The domain attribute is identical in Python and Javascript.

From the [documentation](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#pie-domain):

> `domain`
>
> `x` (array)
>
> default: [0, 1]
>
> Sets the horizontal domain of this pie trace (in plot fraction).
>     Each object has one or more of the keys listed below.

The first member of the array is the start position and the 2nd member is the end position.

For `x` `0` means all the way to the left and `1` is all the way to right.

For `y` `0` is top and `1` is bottom.

e.g. the upper left quadrant would be `x = [0, 0.5]` and `y = [0, 0.5]`

---

If you have multiple plots, e.g. in the example below there are two `div`s with 4 plots each, the domain of each plot specifies which space is occupied by it. In the first example each plot gets a quarter of the available space (i.e. x and y are set to 0 to 0.5 resp. 0.5 to 1).

In the second example the `domain` of the last plot overlaps with the other domains (0.25 to 0.75).

In the third example the `domain` of the last plot is bigger and overlaps with the rest (0 to 0.75).

In short, `domain` just specifies which space of the total plot area is occupied by the subplot.

```js
var allValues = [
  [50, 30, 20],
  [45, 30, 25],
  [55, 25, 20],
  [50, 15, 35]
];

var data = [{
  values: allValues[0],
  type: 'pie',
  domain: {
    x: [0, .5],
    y: [0, .5]
  },
}, {
  values: allValues[1],
  type: 'pie',
  domain: {
    x: [0.5, 1],
    y: [0, .5]
  }
}, {
  values: allValues[2],
  type: 'pie',
  domain: {
    x: [0, .5],
    y: [.5, 1]
  }
}, {
  values: allValues[3],
  type: 'pie',
  domain: {
    x: [0.5, 1],
    y: [0.5, 1]
  },
}];



Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
data[3].domain.x = [0.25, 0.75];
data[3].domain.y = [0.25, 0.75];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv2', data);

data[3].domain.x = [0.0, 0.75];
data[3].domain.y = [0.0, 0.75];
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv3', data);
```

```html
<div id='myDiv'></div>
<div id='myDiv2'></div>
<div id='myDiv3'></div>

<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Would you actually mind explaining what each member of the `x` or `y` actually means? Your answer doesn't provide much more insight the package's own poor documentation.

Comment: @DarthPaghius: I added another paragraph. Let me know if it is clear now.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters I tried using what you've posted in my task but I think I'm doing something wrong that I can't see. Would appreciate it if you could have a look:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55417175/plotting-3-pie-charts-side-by-side-using-the-domain-property.