# Subplots deploying in R Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I would be grateful if anyone could tell me how to specify 
domain layout to get same size pie charts in few columns.
I have already found this example, however, I do not know what each argument of domain option mean and how do resize them and deploy properly, not many info in documentation.

```
plot_ly() %>%
  add_pie(data = count(diamonds, cut), labels = ~cut, values = ~n,
          name = "Cut",domain = list(x = c(0.4, 0.9), y = c(0.4, 1)),hole = 0.6) %>%
  add_pie(data = count(diamonds, color), labels = ~cut, values = ~n,
          name = "Color", domain = list(x = c(0.4, 0.4), y = c(0.4, 1)),hole = 0.6) %>%
  add_pie(data = count(diamonds, clarity), labels = ~cut, values = ~n,
          name = "Clarity", domain = list(x = c(0.4, 0.001), y = c(0.4, 1)),hole = 0.6) %>%
  layout( showlegend = F,autosize=TRUE,
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
```

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotly domain variable explained (Multiple graphs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637341/plotly-domain-variable-explained-multiple-graphs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `domain` specifies the relative range of the complete plot in which the subplot is located. The range is from 0 to 1 and 0 is the lowest/most left part.

In your case if you want to have three columns, you would need the `x` part of the domain would be a sliding window (`(0, 0.3), (0.35, 0.65), (0.7, 1)`) and the `y` part would be constant (`(0, 1)`).

[image]

```
library (plotly)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
plot_ly() %>%
  add_pie(data = count(diamonds, cut), labels = ~cut, values = ~n,
          name = "Cut",domain = list(x = c(0.0, 0.30), y = c(0, 1)),hole = 0.6) %>%
  add_pie(data = count(diamonds, color), labels = ~cut, values = ~n,
          name = "Color", domain = list(x = c(0.35, 0.65), y = c(0, 1)),hole = 0.6) %>%
  add_pie(data = count(diamonds, clarity), labels = ~cut, values = ~n,
          name = "Clarity", domain = list(x = c(0.7, 1), y = c(0, 1)),hole = 0.6) %>%
  layout( showlegend = F,autosize=TRUE,
          xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
          yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
```