# Arrange 4 plotly pie graphs in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, legend, pie-chart

I have four separate pie graphs all with the same specified color scheme (the code is identical apart from the dataframe).

The colors are designated because I want to combine them in the 4 grid graph with one legend using the same designated colors for each of the 5 groups (ie. when the colors are not designated, the colors are automatically allocated based on the size of the group).

Example Data:

```
# Data
g = c("D","L","X","A","N","B")
v = c(49,14,9,7,6,5)

df1 = data.frame(group = g, value = v)
set.seed(9) # Just for reproductibility
df2 = data.frame(group = sample(g,size = nrow(df1),replace = F),
                 value = sample(v,size = nrow(df1),replace = F)
                 )

set.seed(8) 
df3 = data.frame(group = sample(g,size = nrow(df1),replace = F),
                 value = sample(v,size = nrow(df1),replace = F)
)

set.seed(7)
df4 = data.frame(group = sample(g,size = nrow(df1),replace = F),
                 value = sample(v,size = nrow(df1),replace = F)
)
```

[image: piegraph data]

The code:

```
BC <- 

       plot_ly(b_c, labels = ~group, values = ~value, marker = list(colors = c(  '#2ca02c',  '#d62728','#9467bd', '#FF7F0E', '#1F77B4')), type = 'pie',textposition = 'outside',textinfo = 'label+percent') %>%
       layout(title = 'b_c',autosize = F, width = 690, height = 690, margin = m,
              xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
              yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
     BC
```

I have reviewed these posts, but have not been able to determine an answer for combing the plots from these.

[Subplots deploying in R Plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46013559/subplots-deploying-in-r-plotly?rq=1)

[Plotting multiple pie charts in plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47481057/plotting-multiple-pie-charts-in-plotly)

I am looking for something similar to ggarrange in ggplot

I have four sets of data, some of which have the same groups (ie. the same row names). For these I would like to use the same color.

I don't really mind about the color scheme (ie. can be any color), but would like to have a unifying color legend for all 4 piegraphs.

Comment: Could you provide some data @sar ? And if possible the drawn of how the plot sould like and how it looks like now.

Comment: Hmmm I have opened this on another computer and now I am getting this error. Specifying width/height in layout() is now deprecated.
Please specify in ggplotly() or plot_ly()

Comment: @vpz I have added data example. I would like to arrange the 4 piegraphs in a 2x2 square with one legend showing the same colors for the same groups

Comment: I added a suggestion of answer. Does it helps you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi @sar give a look if it solves your problem:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

# Data
g = c("D","L","X","A","N","B")
v = c(49,14,9,7,6,5)

df1 = data.frame(group = g, value = v)
set.seed(9) # Just for reproductibility
df2 = data.frame(group = sample(g,size = nrow(df1),replace = F),
                 value = sample(v,size = nrow(df1),replace = F)
                 )

set.seed(8) 
df3 = data.frame(group = sample(g,size = nrow(df1),replace = F),
                 value = sample(v,size = nrow(df1),replace = F)
)

set.seed(7)
df4 = data.frame(group = sample(g,size = nrow(df1),replace = F),
                 value = sample(v,size = nrow(df1),replace = F)
)


#Plot

plot_ly(labels = ~group, values = ~value, legendgroup = ~group,
        textposition = 'outside',textinfo = 'label+percent') %>%
  add_pie(data = df1, name = "DF1", domain = list(row = 0, column = 0))%>%
  add_pie(data = df2, name = "DF2", domain = list(row = 0, column = 1))%>%
  add_pie(data = df3, name = "DF3", domain = list(row = 1, column = 0))%>%
  add_pie(data = df4, name = "DF4", domain = list(row = 1, column = 1))%>%
  layout(title = "Pie Charts in Grid", showlegend = T,
         grid=list(rows=2, columns=2),
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
```

The Output:

[image: plot]

**EDIT1:**
To show "subtitles" for each pie you can use [annotations](https://plotly.com/r/text-and-annotations/), you can also change the the [legend](https://plotly.com/r/legend/) position. The drawnback of annotations is that you must specify the position(mannualy in this case).

For avoid overlaping I suggest remove `textposition = 'outside'`.

You can download the plot as .png with the button on top right of the plot.

```
#Plot

plot_ly(labels = ~group, values = ~value, legendgroup = ~group, 
        textinfo = 'label+percent') %>%
  add_pie(data = df1, name = "DF1", domain = list(row = 0, column = 0))%>%
  add_pie(data = df2, name = "DF2", domain = list(row = 0, column = 1))%>%
  add_pie(data = df3, name = "DF3", domain = list(row = 1, column = 0))%>%
  add_pie(data = df4, name = "DF4", domain = list(row = 1, column = 1))%>%
  layout(title = "Pie Charts in Grid", showlegend = T,
         grid=list(rows=2, columns=2),
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         legend = list(y = 0.5),
         annotations = list(x = c(.08, .62, .08, .62),
                            y = c(.78, .78, .22, .22),
                            text = c("Pie 1","Pie 2","Pie 3","Pie 4"),
                            xref = "papper",
                            yref = "papper",
                            showarrow = F
                          )
         )
```

The new output is:
[image: plot2]

**EDIT2:**
 Give a look in [font](https://plotly.com/r/font/) or [text font](https://plotly.com/r/text-and-annotations/#customize-text-template).

You can change text and hover text as you please with a [template](https://plotly.com/r/hover-text-and-formatting/).

Here is an edit suggesting taking off the labels to get more space for percentage and rounding percentage to 1 decimal digit:

```
#Plot

plot_ly(labels = ~group, values = ~value, legendgroup = ~group, textinfo = 'label+percent',
        texttemplate = "%{percent:.1%}",
        hovertemplate = "%{label} <br> %{percent:.1%} <br> %{value}") %>%
  add_pie(data = df1, name = "DF1", domain = list(row = 0, column = 0))%>%
  add_pie(data = df2, name = "DF2", domain = list(row = 0, column = 1))%>%
  add_pie(data = df3, name = "DF3", domain = list(row = 1, column = 0))%>%
  add_pie(data = df4, name = "DF4", domain = list(row = 1, column = 1))%>%
  layout(title = "Pie Charts in Grid", showlegend = T,
         grid=list(rows=2, columns=2),
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         legend = list(y = 0.5),
         annotations = list(x = c(.08, .62, .08, .62),
                            y = c(.78, .78, .22, .22),
                            text = c("Pie 1","Pie 2","Pie 3","Pie 4"),
                            xref = "papper",
                            yref = "papper",
                            showarrow = F
                          )
         )
```

New Output:

[image: plot3]

Comment: that's great, thanks. I am just wondering about two things. Is it possible to give a label to each of the graphs or at least a letter (A,B,C,D). Also in my larger data set I have 20 variables, some that are tiny proportions of the pie, so they overlap. Do you have any suggestions as to how to not overly these labels?  Perhaps put a * and a footnote that lists those that are <1% of the pie?

Comment: also this comes up under the viewer tab, 'show in next window', is there a way to save it as a .tiff or .png?

Comment: Hi @sar I made an edit right now. I hope it helps you

Comment: thanks. The labels pie 1,2,3,4 have come up. I am still having difficulty with lots of overlying small groups. Any ideas of how to group them as <2% and represent as a footnote?

Comment: is there a way round the percentages to one digit? I tried adding digits=1 to the first line but this caused an error.  Is there a way to make the size of the pie charts much bigger and the text smaller to avoid the overlaps ?

Comment: I really do not know hou to put foot notes and ommit low percentage groups.
But you can adjust text format and hovertext format as you please.
Give a look an Edit 2

Comment: that last edit has much improved the chart alot, thanks! Some of the lines are off the chart, is there are way to make the charts all fit in? Also, is there a way to adjust the legend text?

Comment: Is there a way to export as pdf or image file?

Comment: Hi @sar
Sorry I did not understant what you mean with "lines are off the chart" could you put an image in comments?

For legends, position can be adjusted in the lines of code `legend = list(...)`. I belive that you can adjust `text font` for legends there too.

Comment: Hi @vpz. Sorry, I meant the lines leading to the sections of the pie. I will try those suggestions

Comment: when I save this as png, it becomes smaller and the 4 pie labels overlap the pies. The pie labels also start to overlap and some of the label lines go off the page. Is there a way to preserve the size formatting (or specify the size) as a png file?

Comment: I tried the     legend = list(y = 0.5, text= c("label1", "label2", "label3")),  but although the code ran without errors, it did not change the labels of the legend

Comment: @sar another solution to save an image is to run code on console and generate the plot in Viwer pane(Tipicaly on the right bottom side of Rstudio).

And then click in `Export` and save image as .PNG. There you can epecify the dimensions mannualy

Comment: Other approach to Modify labels is to build another column in each `data.frame` with desired Labels. Something like : `df1 = df1 %>% mutate(new_lab = case_when(...))`

Comment: is there a way to increase the vertical space between the pie graphs and a the bottom, so that the legend annotations are not cut off?

Comment: When I make the size bigger with   grid=list(rows=2, columns=2), height = 950, width=1650, I get a large plot but it still cuts off the bottom. Also I can't can't if using the export tool as it is too big and only 1/4 of the plot will save

Comment: Did you try enlarge `fig.width` and `fig.height`?

Comment: i've tried altering the width and height of the pie charts in this part of the code, but it doesn't fix my issue of overlaping labels.    layout(title = "title", showlegend = T,
         grid=list(rows=2, columns=2), height = 800, width=1200,margin = m,

Comment: To answer my own question - the best way to stop the figures overlapping is to alter the margins       m = list(
  l = 200,
  r = 200,
  b = 200,
  t = 200,
  pad = 0
)

Comment: do you know how to make the legend boxes bigger? Also is there a way to allocate a list of colors?

Comment: Maybe you can use `layout(font = list(...))`:

https://plotly.com/r/font/