# Plotting 3 pie charts side-by-side using the domain property

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to plot 3 pie charts side by side. I don't understand why the following code is making the pie charts go across the page diagonally left to write rather than horizontally left to write in one line.

Here's my code:

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='TPiePlot',
                  figure={
                      'data': [go.Pie(labels=labels1,
                                      values=values1,
                                      marker=dict(colors=colors, line=dict(color='#fff', width=1)),
                                      hoverinfo='label+value+percent', textinfo='value',
                                      domain={'x': [0, .25], 'y': [0, 1]}
                                      )
                               ],
                      'layout': go.Layout(title='T',
                                          autosize=True
                                          )
                  }
                  ),
        dcc.Graph(id='RPiePlot',
                  figure={
                      'data': [go.Pie(labels=labels2,
                                      values=values2,
                                      marker=dict(colors=colors, line=dict(color='#fff', width=1)),
                                      hoverinfo='label+value+percent', textinfo='value',
                                      domain={'x': [0.30, .55], 'y': [0, 1]}
                                      )
                               ],
                      'layout': go.Layout(title='R',
                                          autosize=True
                                          )
                  }
                  ),

        dcc.Graph(id='RoPiePlot', 
                  figure={
                      'data': [go.Pie(labels=labels3,
                                      values=values3,
                                      marker=dict(colors=colors, line=dict(color='#fff', width=1)),
                                      hoverinfo='label+value+percent', textinfo='value',
                                      domain={'x': [0.60, 0.85], 'y': [0, 1]}
                                      )
                               ],
                      'layout': go.Layout(title='Ro',
                                          autosize=True
                                          )
                  }
                  )
    ])
])
```

Here is what's happening with option 1 from accepted answer (which is the one I need to go with). I'm getting three different sizes plus legend covering some of the pie chart:

[image]

I'm struggling to understand how to re-size dash graphs using CSS because the whole container increases in size rather than the actual graph and I don't know how to target just the graphs themself to make size bigger. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plotly's `domain` is used for subplots. In your case you are plotting three individual plots one after the other and for each you are setting the domain separately.

You have at least two options:

1. Use the approach you are using now, i.e. 3 individual plots, and use CSS to define their position
2. Create one plot with three figures and use `domain` to adjust their position.

**Option 1**

```
import dash
import flask
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import dash_core_components as dcc

server = flask.Flask('app')
app = dash.Dash('app', server=server,
                external_stylesheets=['https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'])

labels = [['monkeys', 'elephants'],
          ['birds', 'dinosaurs'],
          ['unicorns', 'giraffes']]

values = [[50, 40],
          [100, 10],
          [100, 20]]

data = []

for label, value in zip(labels, values):
    data.append(html.Div([dcc.Graph(figure={'data': [go.Pie(labels=label,
                                                            values=value,
                                                            hoverinfo='label+value+percent', textinfo='value'
                                                            )]})
                          ], className='col-sm-4'))

app.layout = html.Div(data, className='row')

app.run_server()
```

[image]

**Option 2**

```
import dash
import flask
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import dash_core_components as dcc

server = flask.Flask('app')
app = dash.Dash('app', server=server)

labels = [['monkeys', 'elephants'],
          ['birds', 'dinosaurs'],
          ['unicorns', 'giraffes']]

values = [[50, 40],
          [100, 10],
          [100, 20]]

data = []
x1 = 0
x2 = 0.25
for label, value in zip(labels, values):
    data.append(go.Pie(labels=label,
                       values=value,
                       hoverinfo='label+value+percent', textinfo='value',
                       domain={'x': [x1, x2], 'y': [0, 1]}
                                      )
                )
    x1 = x1 + 0.30
    x2 = x1 + 0.25



app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([dcc.Graph(figure={'data': data})])
])


app.run_server()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Is there a way to separate the legends in option 2 in any way so we can tell which legends belong to which pie chart?

In your example you have 2 values so it looks good. I have many values in each pie chart so looking to make the legend slightly clearer.

Comment: Not really, the idea is to join similar graphs

Comment: Oh I see. In that case I will go for option 1. But the issue I have is because I have many values, the pie charts come out different size or one gets covered up entirely by the legend (updated the question to show it). Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Can you open a separate question and add the data to create the graph?

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55421040/plotly-pie-charts-side-by-side-sizing-issue-image-contained .