# How to change the size of pie chart traces?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, plotly

I have the following code that plots 2 Pie charts and places them on top of each other. I want to make the total radius of the inner Pie chart smaller so that there is some gap between the two donuts, and the labels for the inner donut appear centered and not hidden behind the outer one.

I just want to change the relative size of the two traces, and not the entire figure, so `fig.update_layout()` does not work for me.

```py
import plotly.graph_objs as go


labels_1 = ['Server 1','Server 2','Server 3','Server 4']
values_1 = [4500, 2500, 1053, 500]
trace_1 = go.Pie(labels=labels_1, values=values_1, hole=.7)

labels_2 = ['Client 1','Client 2']
values_2 = [4500, 2184]
trace_2 = go.Pie(labels=labels_2, values=values_2, hole=.3)

fig = go.Figure(data=[trace_2, trace_1])
fig.show()
```

Currently, my nested pychart looks like this:

[image: The Pie Chart as it is right now]

Comment: Would a sunburst diagram work as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pie trace markers don't have a direct `width` or `size` attribute. So it seems to me that you'll have to handle this case through a combination of `hole` (like you're already doing) *and* `domain` like this:

```
fig.data[0].domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0.25, 0.75]}
```

#### Plot

[image]

#### complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go

labels_1 = ['Server 1','Server 2','Server 3','Server 4']
values_1 = [4500, 2500, 1053, 500]
trace_1 = go.Pie(labels=labels_1, values=values_1, hole=.6)

labels_2 = ['Client 1','Client 2']
values_2 = [4500, 2184]
trace_2 = go.Pie(labels=labels_2, values=values_2, hole=.3)

fig = go.Figure(data=[trace_2, trace_1])
f = fig.full_figure_for_development(warn=False)
fig.update_layout(width = 1400)
fig.data[0].domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0.25, 0.75]}
fig.show()
```

Comment: Could u give me a hint on what `domain` does, as `plotly` apprentice?

Comment: @Albo Sure! [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637341/plotly-domain-variable-explained-multiple-graphs)